# Why isn't my new object being seen? C#

Tags: c#, object

I am getting ready to take a class at a college on C#.  I have been reading up on it a lot and decided to start a fun project.

Here is what my project consists of:

- Main Control Form
- Configuration Form
- Arduino

*Program.cs* calls *Configuration.cs* at start.  This is where pin modes for the Arduino are set and where a timer is set.  When I set these values, they get sent to *MainControl.cs*.  When I hit the "Save" button in Configuration.cs, a *MainControl.cs* object is created [[I am correct in that?]]

All of those values that were sent by *Configuration.cs* had corresponding setters that set private static variables in *MainControl.cs*  [[ I don't really know if that is the preferred way, I am most definetly open to any suggestion anyone has]]

*MainControl.cs* uses its default constructor, and this constructor calls a method that creates an arduino object from one of the private variables (serialPort) [[ Using this Arduino class [Firmata.NET](http://www.imagitronics.org/projects/firmatanet/)  ]]

When the arduino object is created, I know (I guess I do) because the form takes a few seconds to come up (As opposed to not using serial port)  My problem is this:

I do not understand why nothing can see the object

I have been very wordy, I apologize if I wasn't concise.  Here is the code:

```
public partial class CMainControl : Form
{
       private static string serialPort;
        public CMainControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        createArduino();
        updateConfig();  // Change label values to values set in configuration
    }

    private void createArduino()
    {
        Arduino arduino = new Arduino(serialPort);
    }
```

In *Configuration.cs*, when I set the serial port through a combobox, the value is sent to *MainControl.cs* just fine.

Here is the error I get:

> Error    1   The name 'arduino' does not
>   exist in the current
>   context   C:\Programming\Visual
>   Studio\Workhead Demo\Workhead
>   Demo\CMainControl.cs  94  13  Workhead
>   Demo

Please let me know if anyone can help and/or offer pointers, and please let me know if I didn't post or format anything correctly.

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try defining the Arduino variable as field in the CMainControl class.

```
public partial class CMainControl : Form
{
   private Arduino arduino;
   private static string serialPort;

    private void createArduino()
    {
        arduino = new Arduino(serialPort);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing, as I'm not sure I wholly followed that, but I'm guessing it's becuase your arduino object is declared locally inside your create method and won't be accessible by anybody outside that method.

Comment: That was it, now I know :)  

Thank you for your help